# How to write a biconditional $P\leftrightarrow Q$, into a form using only connectives: $\to, \land, \bot$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Take $P\longleftrightarrow Q$.

I am struggling to understand how to rewrite this proposition as an equivalent proposition, using only the two connectives: $\;\;\to,\;\; \bot$

If someone could further explain how this can be managed thanks in advance.

Comment: Austin: I edited your post, and when I did, I took `&` to mean the connective $\land$.  If you were trying to specify that you were limited to two connectives, those being $\rightarrow, \bot$, I will surely edit again to correct the edit.

Comment: It was only those two connectives but thanks to Mauro I was able to understand with a simply equivalency!

Comment: I've make the appropriate (re-)edit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P \leftrightarrow Q$ is equivalent to :

> $(P \to Q) \land (Q \to P)$.

In turn, $A \land B$ is equivalent to :

> $(A \to (B \to \bot)) \to \bot$.

Comment: I took the question to mean that only the connectives $\rightarrow, \land , \bot$

Comment: I.e., I took the OP's use of the symbol `&` to mean the connective $\land$.

Comment: @amWhy - in that case, the OP has a "bonus" answer...

Comment: Yes indeed! Nice job!